# load image from database and asset folder at same time to listview android

Tags: android

I successful an retrieving in image from sqlitedatabse and loading in to listview , but I too have a image path of assets folder , loaded to database like  `"file:///android_asset/pisces.png"` . I need to get the path from database and convert to bitmap and load to listview . I successful in doing these steps ,but don't know how to load image from database and asset at same time to listview

SearchViewBinder.java //loading image from database

```
public class SearchViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder, ViewBinder{

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if(view instanceof ImageView)
        {
            Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;
            ImageView iv=(ImageView) view;
            byte[] img=cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
            iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length));
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }

}
```

list_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <!-- THUMBAIL IMAGE -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:shadowColor="#585858"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="20"
            android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

SearchListActivity.java

```
public class SearchListActivity extends ListActivity {

    String from[];
    int to[];
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;



    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_list_activity);
        Cursor cursor;
        CursorLoader cursorLoader=new CursorLoader(this,BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null,null);
        cursor=cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        from=new String[]{BirthdayProvider.PHOTO,BirthdayProvider.NAME,BirthdayProvider.NUMBER,BirthdayProvider.CATEGORY,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_TYPE,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DAY,BirthdayProvider.TURNS_AGE,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_WEEK,BirthdayProvider.WESTERN_ZODIAC,BirthdayProvider.DAYS_REMAINING};
        to=new int[]{R.id.list_image,R.id.title_name,R.id.sub_title_contact_number,R.id.sub_title_category,R.id.txtview_type_of_reminder,R.id.sub_title_birthdate,R.id.txtview_turns,R.id.txtview_next_bd,R.id.txtview_zodiac,R.id.txtview_days_left};
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to);
            adapter.setViewBinder(new SearchViewBinder());
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im sorry but i dont get what you are trying to achieve here as its pretty difficult to understand what you are saying. I dont get the meaning of this: "but I too have a image path of assets folder , loaded to database like "file:///android_asset/pisces.png" ." you have images in your assets, but what exactly do you want to do with them? put them in db?

Comment: I saved the path "file:///android_asset/pisces.png". I need to load the path as image file to Imageview in Listview

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Comment: I am aware of how to go with assets .... but the thing is, I want to load image from database and assets at the same time to the listview ,I amnot aware of this....

Comment: you can start loading them at the same time, but you cant be sure that their loading will finish at the same time. You will have to take care of that yourself

Comment: Sir ,my question is how can I include the assets image loading code in my SearchViewBinder.java